# PBR Texture Direction

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to create a very basic page texture (over the top example used here for visuals) and I'm a little more than stumped. I am using a simple procedural texture and do not want to make use of jpgs for this project.

First, let me just say that my modelling and mapping skills are 25+ years out-of-date and I'm somewhat new to blender ... I'm shooting in the dark with this problem.

The model is a basic open book which has some modifiers applied to provide the page thickness and curvature.

When I apply the basic PBR texture I can't figure out how to get the texture to follow the curvature of the geometry.

[image: basic open softcover book]

As shown above with the green arrows, I can't get the (red) direction to follow the geometry.

I'm including the blender file here [if you're curious](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hh2apz9nbu15ckt/pbr-follow-geometry.blend.zip?dl=0).

One bit of frustration is with the modifiers — if I disable/remove or touch a modifier then the texture magically follows the geometry and remains good until we close the file.  Then it reverts back to the directions shown in the image. Unfortunately when I render the book using a custom python script the direction reverts to what's seen in the image as well.

Any practical help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this would be to preserve the mesh coordinates *before* deformation, one way or another, and use those to guide the procedural texture.

The *Generated* texture-space will do this for you

Here, the pages are a subdivided cube, with the near-side sloped, deformed with a *Curve* modifier:

[image]

Above, the *Generated* space is hooked in. An alternative is also given, which would be to stash the pre-deformed coordinates on the mesh-vertices using Geometry Nodes, and to access those from the shader-tree.

The *Multiply* and *Combine XYZ* nodes are just to make fine-tuning of the Z of the texture easier, to get white on the top surface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the moiré pattern in the picture, should have made thick pages to illustrate.

Comment: Sorry, I got so lost in life I forgot to return and thank you for this answer.  It was very helpful to us.

Comment: @ubuntux  God forbid... Real Life! :D Thanks. No Problem.